# deployment not picking up secret password

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I'm trying to add mysql root password as a secret to my kubernetes deployment and it doesn't seem to be picking it up.  This is what I have

deployment:

```
   env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: mysql-root
          key: mysql-root-passwd
```

secret:

```
kubectl create secret generic mysql-root --from-literal=mysql-root-passwd=steve
```

but when I go into the pod the mysql root password for % and localhost is always the same:

`*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19` which is `'password'` in Base64 decode

What am I doing wrong?  when I set the password in the deployment file it works just fine but I'd prefer not to have it there.

Comment: can you verify environment variable is working by issuing "env | grep MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" ?

Comment: @sgarre02 can you chek if env variable has been set  `kubectl exec -it <POD-NAME> env|grep MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` Also, where do you get this passord from `*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
kubectl create secret generic mysql-root \
  --from-literal=mysql-root-passwd=steve --dry-run -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

as I don't think you can create when it already exists

[link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65066)

Comment: Hi,  thanks for all the suggestions.  I guess maybe I should clarify, if I set the root password as an env variable does that get passed to mysql when the container is getting spun up or is that not how it works.  It only sets the environment variable to what’s on the secret?

Answer (score 0):

I always create using the `yml` file with `create -f` command and it accepts `base64` encoded string.

Please check using base64 of your password and get the secret as yaml.

See link: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/